# Can I cover conduit bodies alongside a service panel with plywood?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, walls

I am interested in feedback on how I plan to reconstruct the wall around my main panel.

The panel is in a finished area of the basement. The walls in this area were constructed with studs set a couple of inches out from the foundation, 1/2" drywall on the studs, 1 x 3 strapping over that, and 3/4" rough-faced shiplap on the strapping. The shiplap was originally unpainted dark brown, I think this was supposed to create a “hunting lodge” appearance.

In the first photo below the shiplap and strapping have been removed, along with enough drywall to gain access to the areas where wires enter. The LB on the right side is a feed to a subpanel elsewhere in the basement. It was buried behind all those layers of wall, I didn't realize it was there until I took off the drywall.

The new wall around the panel can be a single layer, we don't like the shiplap and there's no reason to replace it in this wall, we're happy with just a regular flat surface (we don't plan to redo it elsewhere, removing the shiplap and strapping is a huge pain). And I believe putting it back around the panel would be a code violation anyway, because the panel is only 1/2" proud of the studs, and that wall was 2” thick in total, so the panel was recessed when it needed to be flush.

The second photo shows where I would replace the drywall and add a little bit of new framing. There is fiberglass batt insulation behind the drywall. The new (short) stud is about 8" to the left of the stud the panel is on -- i.e. halfway across the existing stud bay. I would make it a 2 x 3, leaving plenty of room behind it. (The loose wires in the stud bay to the left of the panel have labels that say “disconnected,” they're old feeds to removed 240-volt baseboard heaters.)

I want to maintain access to the areas to the left of the panel and above it for any future changes, and code requires access at the right due to the LB. It seemed easiest to do three 1/2" plywood access panels as shown in the third photo. Panels A and B are 8 - 10” wide, C is about 12”. A and C are about 36” high. Each would be attached with removable screws which are readily visible (no plugs over them or anything like that). Panel C could in theory be broken up into multiple panels with a center one over the LB and the others permanently installed but that just seems like extra trouble.

The cement block foundation wall behind this is an exterior load-bearing wall, but the part I’m working on is an interior non load-bearing wall constructed only to finish the basement, so as far as I know there is no fire resistance rating required. So I plan to use 1/2" plywood for the access panels.

So, questions:

Any electrical code issues you see with constructing the wall this way?
Any other issues in terms of wall construction or fire rating?
Best way to insulate the areas behind the access panels? There was fiberglass batting there before but I'm tempted to glue 2” inch rigid foam to the back of the access panels instead, so that you don't have to pull out the fiberglass batts to gain access.
Anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

[image: Current construction]

[image: New framing and drywall]

[image: Access panels]

Answer (score 4):

By code panel C must open without tools. You could use hinges and a cupboard door catch, or magnets, etc.

Another option could be to swap the back-exit conduit body with a side-exit body (left, in this case, or LL) and cut an oval opening to access it.

I'd put plywood below the electrical panel too, just for looks. You can paint the plywood the same color as the drywall, but a different finish (e.g., satin or semi-gloss) than the drywall. Or you can paint it a contrasting color, though perhaps not as bold as the blue and green of the pictures in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The colors in the picture are just to show the areas, really it will all be white. Good idea about using different sheens. I had thought about putting an access panel below, more for functional than aesthetic reasons, but you make a good point on that also. On panel C, it would indeed be very easy to make it removable without tools, but I don’t think that’s necessary to meet code. I've seen that come up elsewhere as well as here so I'll post a separate question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, is to replace the conduit section visible in the wall so it is a compound sweep (swinging to vertical than a 90 going into the panel).  The trick to such a complex bend is couplers. Use couplers to join several simple bends.

The only trick with an LL is because there's a sharp bend getting into the shorter passage, there are some rules limiting the size of the wire. I'm not well versed on that particular rule, though.

For smaller wires, they also make a conduit fitting which has a relatively sharp elbow and a threaded fitting. It can only be installed at the very end of the conduit (because you often have to reach in with needle-nose pliers to pull the wire in). But again due to the wire bending rules, these may not be allowed for larger wires.

Comment: Harper I agree it would be great to do this with a compound sweep, but I don't think there’s space for it in the area between the panel and the chimney. The existing conduit is a straight piece that runs behind the chimney and is bent 90 degrees at the end to go into the LB. I would need to cut it back and put in two sweeps with couplers, and have it match up vertically to the panel knockout. I suspect it’s a lot simpler to just make the panel removable, though the sweep would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I did find some EMT to box pull elbows, maybe these are what you were thinking of? But they only seem to be available up to 1-1/4". For example, https://sigmaengineeredsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/PEEB_Main-1024x661.jpg

Comment: @Trawson Oh! I thought that was a custom bend, now I see that is a 90 sweep *on bigger conduit than I thought*.  No, forget that.   I was thinking more like an ["EMT 90 degree connector"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-1-2-in-Electrical-Metallic-Tube-EMT-90-Compression-Elbow-90291/100128279) which needs no access ports, but they don't make those in large size either, probably that bending radius issue again.

Comment: Thanks. Also, re a compound sweep, I'm not sure I conveyed the situation clearly. The conduit is 1½”, a subpanel feed. Right now the bend above the LB *is* a custom bend, not a sweep. I was talking about the possibility of cutting the conduit back before the bend to gain as much horizontal room as possible, then putting in two sweeps – that’s what I thought you meant by a compound sweep. But 1½”, 90° sweeps seem to require 11¾” in each dimension, and there's only about 18” vertically and at most 15” horizontally between the straight part of the existing conduit and the knockout.